# 'Input' does not name a type error. Can't figure out why?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, codeblocks

When I compile, i get the error: 'Input' does not name a type on line 17

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include "input.h"

// Can forward declare "class Input(GLFWwindow*);" here but it still
//     gives the same error.

class Game
{
    public:
        Game(Input* input);
        ~Game();

        void Input();
        void Update();
        void Render();

    private:
        Input* mpInput; //error here.
};

#endif // GAME_H
```

Input.h looks like this.

```
#ifndef INPUT_H
#define INPUT_H

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <vector>

class Input
{
    public:
        Input(GLFWwindow* window);
        ~Input();
        bool GetKey(int keyCode);
        bool GetKeyDown(int keyCode);
        bool GetKeyUp(int keyCode);
        void Update();

    private:
        GLFWwindow* mpWindow;
        std::vector<bool> mCurrentKeys;
        std::vector<bool> mDownKeys;
        std::vector<bool> mUpKeys;
        const int NUM_KEYCODES = 256;
};

#endif // INPUT_H
```

I have no clue what is going on here. I had a similar problem yesterday, and couldn't figure it out, so I tried saving the project, closing Code::Blocks, restarting Code::Blocks, and reopening the project. Then I compiled it and it worked for no apparent reason. No code was changed or anything. I tried reloading the project here too, but it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have method `Input` in your class code. Mixing names of methods and types is generally a bad idea. Consider this code in one of your class `Game` methods:

```
Input();
```

Is this a method `Input` call or you are trying to create `Input` class instance? Try renaming your `Input` method.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Probably would have taken me ages to notice that, and think that it might be the problem!